# Eclipse predict the direction of submenu in popup

Tags: java, eclipse

How to know where eclipse will open the next sub menu inside popup. 
For example in Java Class file, right click and the menu appears, mouse over an item which has sub menu.

Even when there is enough space most of the time it is illusive. Is there a rule of thumb for correctly predicting eclipse behavior

cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want but you might try customizing your Java perspective: **Window->Perspective->Customize Perspective...**

You'll have to look through the tabs (2 of which I included) to see what can be done.

[image]

[image]

[image]